# jquery mouseleave event not being fired when quickly hovering over nav link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown navigation where I want to slide up and down a dropdown which works fine, what I've found however is that if I hover over the link quickly the nav links dont disappear, I've tried adding stop(true,true) etc but with no success. Can anyone advise on how I can resolve this?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/9QdhN/3/

**JS**

```
mouseleave: function() {        

        if( !isActive ) {
        inner.stop(true,true).fadeOut('fast', function(){
            if (topLevelLinks.children('.sub-nav').filter(":visible").length === 0) {
                subNav.stop(true,true).slideUp();
            }
        });
        }
    }  

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `isActive` variable, jQuery does this for you in the `stop()` method.

Here's the fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/9QdhN/7/